# Solution of p-Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

If $u$ is a solution of $\Delta_p u=0$ weakly, then $u^{+}$ is also satisfies $\Delta_p v=0$ weakly.
To prove this result, I need to prove that 
$$
\int_{\Omega}|\nabla v|^{p-2}\nabla v.\nabla \phi\,dx=0
$$ 
where $v=u^{+}$ for every $\phi\in W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)$,
whereas I know that 
$$
\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u.\nabla \phi\,dx=0\:\text{ for every }\:\phi\in W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega).$$

Can you please help me with this one?

Comment: I don't believe this is true. Consider the 1D-case, where $\Delta_p u = 0$ just means that $u$ is linear.

Comment: Thanks, but what about if $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ for $N\geq 2$?

Comment: The same. If $u$ is a counterexample in 1D, then $v(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = u(x_1)$ is a counterexample in $n$ dimensions.